# rails - how to make module for common regular expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, module

i use about 3 - 4 common Reqular Expressions inside most of models. so i want to put these regular expressions in module to use them directly instead of repeating it in every model. how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module CommonRegularExpressions
  REGULAR_EXPRESSION_1 = /one/
  REGULAR_EXPRESSION_2 = /two/
end

class OverHere
  def call_me(input)
    return input[CommonRegularExpressions.REGULAR_EXPRESSION_1]
  end
end

class WithInclude
  include CommonRegularExpressions

  def call_me_too(input)
    return input.scan(REGULAR_EXPRESSION_2)
  end
end
```

Comment: the syntax use inside module won't work for me, so i changed it to be: `def self.name_regex
    /name-regex/
  end`